# Impact of Share Button on Web Page Performance

Tags: php, javascript, performance, html

On a few websites that I maintain, I noticed that adding a share button like AddThis to a page varyingly slows down page loading, sometimes significantly.

What is the explanation for this and what can be done to keep share buttons while not incurring page loading performance penalty for this?

Comment: Does the button contain elements that are hosted off site? (thinking images, or scripts)

Comment: @Leigh The answer is Yes. The problem is that those offsites don't exhibit consistent performance and while this doesn't always hurt performance by much, there are too many instances in which this has become a problem -- prompting me to give up on these useful widgets.

Comment: Well you answered your own question with regard to the explanation why :)

Comment: @Leigh You are correct about the first question. As for the second question, only @capdragon provided a possible way to mitigate this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the script call to the bottom of your page, that's what i do, right on top of `</body>`.

```
...

all my html

...
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;username=xa-4d4c6a9028bcda9b" class="addthis_button_compact">Share</a>
<span class="addthis_separator">|</span>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
</div>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
...

all my html

...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=xa-4d4c6a9028bcda9b"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: By moving the script call to the bottom of the page your page will load before the script and your users will not feel the impact.

Comment: But only the javascript moved to the bottom of the page. What about the PHP script (that depending on page layout may need to be at the top) http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php ?

Comment: @Android By moving the script call to the bottom of the page your page will load before the script and your users will not feel the impact.
I don't see what PHP script you're refering to. Did you make the php script?

Answer (score 1):

@Anodroid - I would leave your PHP at the top.. PHP scripts will be dependant on the processing speed of your server and the javascript will be determined first on the connection speed to the host "http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&username=xa-4d4c6a9028bcda9b" and how fast they can server the content to be embedded on page "|



"

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I can only accept one answer so I will give you a +1. :)